# Why can't I get any .m file to work in octave?

Tags: octave

I am desperately trying to run octave in a VirtualBox of Ubuntu 12.04. I have made a file called ANGRY.m which has lines as follows:

```
%How badly does octave suck?

OCTAVESUCKS=5
```

That is it. When I try to run it (i.e. enter ANGRY into the command line I get this error message:

```
error: `ANRGY' undefined near line 1 column 1
```

I've had things running better than this in octave and have absolutely no clue why it is doing this or how to fix it or how to go about trying to search for what is wrong. I am sorry I cannot be more helpful. But I really can't. Please aim any answer at a total moron. I'm really not a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `ANGRY` when you put it into the terminal...

Comment: I actually did do that the first time I became so desperate I tried to run this code. That's not the answer unfortunately.

Comment: What error did you get when you spelled `ANGRY` correctly?

Comment: Exactly the same. (Like it isn't there or octave can't read in anything.)

Comment: if you put in ANRGY you get ANRGY in the error description. If you put in ANGRY you get ANGRY in the error description.

Comment: Oysh I've figured it out. For some reason it has reset the directory to my home directory. No wonder it can't find it!

Comment: Going to try running it now. Huzzah! OCTAVESUCKS=5

Answer (score 0):

Do you see your file ANGRY.m when you type

```
ls
```

in Octave? Check the working dir with "pwd"!